# How to use GroupBy with Join in Linq's method syntax in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query:

```
            var chat_AppUsers = _context.Chat_AppUsers;
            var chats = _context.Chats;

            var chat_lists = chat_AppUsers.Join(chats,
                ca => ca.ChatId,
                c => c.ChatId,
                (ca, c) => new
                {
                    ChatId = ca.ChatId,
                    ChatType = c.ChatType,
                    chat_AppUsers = c.chat_AppUsers
                }
            ).ToList();

            var grouped_list = chat_lists
            .GroupBy(c => c.ChatId);
```

Basically, I want a list of all chats with their users by `ChatId`, like:

```
  "result": [
    {
      "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
      "chat_AppUsers": [
        {
          "chat_AppUserId": "Chat_AppUserId_1",
          "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
          "chat": null,
          "appUserId": "bob_id",
          "appUser": null
        },
        {
          "chat_AppUserId": "Chat_AppUserId_2",
          "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
          "chat": null,
          "appUserId": "alice_id",
          "appUser": null
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
```

But `GroupBy` doesn't group by the unique `ChatId` of `alice_bob_id_1`, and since I have two users in `Chat_AppUsers`, I get the duplicate result below instead:

```
  "result": [
    {
      "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
      "chat_AppUsers": [
        {
          "chat_AppUserId": "Chat_AppUserId_1",
          "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
          "chat": null,
          "appUserId": "bob_id",
          "appUser": null
        },
        {
          "chat_AppUserId": "Chat_AppUserId_2",
          "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
          "chat": null,
          "appUserId": "alice_id",
          "appUser": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
      "chat_AppUsers": [
        {
          "chat_AppUserId": "Chat_AppUserId_1",
          "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
          "chat": null,
          "appUserId": "bob_id",
          "appUser": null
        },
        {
          "chat_AppUserId": "Chat_AppUserId_2",
          "chatId": "alice_bob_id_1",
          "chat": null,
          "appUserId": "alice_id",
          "appUser": null
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
```

I am a beginner in Linq, and wasn't able to find examples of using `Join` with `GroupBy` using method syntax anywhere.

Thanks and much appreciated,

Comment: From your example, it looks like you don't need `_context.Chats` at all; seeing as the only thing you are using is the `ChatId`, which is also found in the objects in `_context.Chat_AppUsers`. Is that the case, or have you provided a simplified example that omits the relevance of other `Chat` properties?

Comment: My bad @AstridE. as I did not include `ChatType` which only exists on `_context.Chats`, I have fixed by adding the line `ChatType = c.ChatType` to be selected as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the method syntax of linq is very hard to understand
I prefer to use query syntax

```
        var query = from chatAppUser in _context.Chat_AppUser
                    join chat in _context.Chat
                    on chatAppUser.ChatId equals chat.Id
                    select new
                    {
                        ChatId = chat.Id,
                        Chat_AppUser = chat.Chat_AppUsers
                    };
```

but there is also an easier way to join two tables

```
            var query = _context.Chat.Include(i => i.Chat_AppUser).ToList();
```

and for your question ..

the GroupBy Element in Linq is a key value IEnumerable of IGrouping

The GroupBy operator returns a group of elements from the given collection based on some key value. Each group is represented by IGrouping<TKey, TElement> object. from [tutorialsTeacher](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-grouping-operator-groupby-tolookup)

I hope this link can help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve what you want by grouping the `chat_AppUsers` by `ChatId` first, and then join the grouped results with `chats`:

```csharp
var grouped_list = chatAppUsers
    .GroupBy(appUser => appUser.ChatId)
    .Join(chats,
        appUserGroup => appUserGroup.Key,
        chat => chat.ChatId,
        (appUserGroup, chat) => new {
            ChatId = chat.ChatId,
            ChatType = chat.ChatType,
            Chat_AppUsers = appUserGroup
         })
    .ToList();
```

Taking your example, a simplified version of `chat_AppUsers` may look like the following:

```csharp
chat_AppUsers:
{
    ChatId: "alice_bob_id_1",
    AppUserId: "bob_id"
},
{
    ChatId: "alice_bob_id_1",
    AppUserId: "alice_id"
}
```

The [.GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))) operation

```csharp
chatAppUsers.GroupBy(appUser => appUser.ChatId)
```

will group your app users by `ChatId`. The result from the `.GroupBy()` operation can (after enumeration, e.g. after calling `.ToList()`) be visualized as

```csharp
[0]
    Key: "alice_bob_id_1"
    [0]
        ChatId: "alice_bob_id_1"
        AppUserId: "bob_id"
    [1]
        ChatId: "alice_bob_id_1"
        AppUserId: "alice_id"
```

When we then join this grouping with`chats`, based on the grouping's `Key`, the app users are already properly grouped into their respecitve chats.

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n3YvZa).

Comment: Thanks, but with EF Core 6. I get this.
```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Chat_AppUser>()
          .GroupBy(appUser => appUser.ChatId)
          .Join(
              inner: DbSet<Chat>(), 
              outerKeySelector: appUserGroup => appUserGroup.Key, 
              innerKeySelector: chat => chat.ChatId, 
              resultSelector: (appUserGroup, chat) => new { 
                  ChatId = chat.ChatId, 
                  ChatType = chat.ChatType, 
                  Chat_AppUsers = appUserGroup
               })' could not be translated.
```